# sqlite3 timestamp (current_timestamp) one hour off

Tags: cron, sqlite

I run a small crawler on a virtual ubuntu server, initiated by crontab hourly. Datetime is inserted by defaulting the date filed to `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Table creation looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE links (page TEXT, link TEXT, date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY(page,link));
```

The datetime gets stored fine, but it one hour off (one hour behind) Norwegian time (GMT +1). The server is located where-ever, I just need it to be on GMT+1.

By typing `date`in the ssh session I get:

```
Wed Dec 19 17:26:02 CET 2012
```

and that is correct (just now).

So where does sqlite3 get it's time from? What must I do to set the time so that sqlite3 gets the time right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite stores dates in utc. To see a date in localtimezone use the localtime modifier.

```
select datetime(date,'localtime') from links;
```

Comment: Ok. So sqlite stores dates in utc.. in plain text that's just "Western European Time", right? Can I make sqlite store in localtime? (in my case +1 hour)